# sub query returning more than one row

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying a query like this in MYSQL

```
select 
Sum(case when WindowsXP = "PASS" then 1 else 0 end) as PASS ,
Sum(case when WindowsVista = "FAIL" then 1 else 0 end) as FAIL 

from OS_Table where BuildID = (select distinct BuildID from OS_Table)
group by BuildID
```

The error is Subquery returns more than one row. If I use `IN` instead of `=` then the query is going on forever ( nearly after 3 minutes it does not stop)

Basically what I am trying to achieve is for each distinct BuildID, give me counts of PASS, FAIL when WindowsXP = "PASS" and WindowsVista = "FAIL"

I have hardly 10 distinct BuildID's

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove your join, it's redundant:

```
SELECT  buildid,
        SUM(CASE WHEN WindowsXP = 'PASS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as PASS ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN WindowsVista = 'FAIL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FAIL 
FROM    OS_Table
GROUP BY
        buildId
```

This condition

```
WHERE BuildID IN (SELECT DISTINCT BuildID FROM OS_Table)
```

holds for any non-null `buildid` in the table.

**Update:**

Your original query (with `=` operator) meant this: "take all records from the table where `buildId` equals to a single `DISTINCT` value of `buildId` taken from the same table, split them into several groups according to the value of `buildID` and calculate the sums of the expressions within each group".

`=` operator requires a scalar on both sides. In `SQL`, a query is considered a scalar if and only if it returns a recordset of one field and at most one record.

Your subquery returned more that one record, so you original query failed (with quite a descriptive error).

With `IN` operator, the query meant "take all records from the table where `buildId` is found anywhere in the list of `buildId`'s taken from the same table, split them into several groups according to the value of `buildID` and calculate the sums of the expressions within each group".

Since `buildId` is always found the in the list of `buildIs` taken from the same table, the condition is redundant.

Comment: can you please explain me in english what my query meant? and what I am suppose to be doing?

Comment: ok. using the IN operator, is the query going into infinite loop? or when does it stop exactly?

Comment: Seems that your `buildID` field is not indexed. Otherwise, `MySQL` would just use `index_subquery` which would make a single index scan for each `buildId`. Without an index, it has to run the distinct query for each record it parses. This loop is not endless, it's just very long. This condition is just useless anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your output to include all `BuildID`s, you don't need a `WHERE` at all:

```
SELECT
    BuildID
    , SUM(CASE WHEN WindowsXP = "PASS" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PASS
    , SUM(CASE WHEN WindowsVista = "FAIL" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FAIL
FROM
    OS_Table
GROUP BY
    BuildID
```

disclaimer: untested.

Comment: can you please explain me in english what my query meant? and what I am suppose to be doing? I need to understand SQL a lot more